# Hudson Service Won't Start

Tags: windows, hudson

I'm relatively new to Hudson and it's administration.   The gentleman who set it up is no longer with the company.

Last night we had to restart the machine that we host Hudson on and now the Hudson service won't restart.  When I try to restart the service I get the following message in my Event Viewer.

> Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other
>   applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The
>   applications or services that hold your registry file may not function
>   properly afterwards.
>
> DETAIL -   15 user registry handles leaked from
>   \Registry\User\S-1-5-21-2607633282-1266002969-1084313107-1154: Process
>   3436 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\hudsonworkspace\hudson.exe) has opened
>   key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-2607633282-1266002969-1084313107-1154
>   Process 3436 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\hudsonworkspace\hudson.exe) has
>   opened key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-2607633282-1266002969-1084313107-1154 Process
>   3436 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\hudsonworkspace\hudson.exe) has opened
>   key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-2607633282-1266002969-1084313107-1154
>   Process 3436 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\hudsonworkspace\hudson.exe) has
>   opened key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-2607633282-1266002969-1084313107-1154 Process
>   3436 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\hudsonworkspace\hudson.exe) has opened
>   key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-2607633282-1266002969-1084313107-1154
>   Process 3436 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\hudsonworkspace\hudson.exe) has
>   opened key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-2607633282-1266002969-1084313107-1154\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root Process 3436 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\hudsonworkspace\hudson.exe) has
>   opened key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-2607633282-1266002969-1084313107-1154\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\SmartCardRoot
>   Process 3436 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\hudsonworkspace\hudson.exe) has
>   opened key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-2607633282-1266002969-1084313107-1154\Control
>   Panel\International Process 3436
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\hudsonworkspace\hudson.exe) has opened key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-2607633282-1266002969-1084313107-1154\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\trust
>   Process 3436 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\hudsonworkspace\hudson.exe) has
>   opened key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-2607633282-1266002969-1084313107-1154\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\TrustedPeople
>   Process 3436 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\hudsonworkspace\hudson.exe) has
>   opened key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-2607633282-1266002969-1084313107-1154\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Disallowed
>   Process 3436 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\hudsonworkspace\hudson.exe) has
>   opened key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-2607633282-1266002969-1084313107-1154\Software\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates
>   Process 3436 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\hudsonworkspace\hudson.exe) has
>   opened key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-2607633282-1266002969-1084313107-1154\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My
>   Process 3436 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\hudsonworkspace\hudson.exe) has
>   opened key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-2607633282-1266002969-1084313107-1154\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\CA
>   Process 3436 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\hudsonworkspace\hudson.exe) has
>   opened key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-2607633282-1266002969-1084313107-1154\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer

In my Error log I see the below statement.

> May 06, 2014 5:11:59 AM hudson.Proc$LocalProc join WARNING: Process
>   leaked file descriptors. See
>   http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Spawning+processes+from+build
>   for more information java.lang.Exception  at
>   hudson.Proc$LocalProc.join(Proc.java:234)     at
>   hudson.plugins.tfs.TfTool.execute(TfTool.java:104)    at
>   hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Server.execute(Server.java:47)   at
>   hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Project.getDetailedHistory(Project.java:41)
>     at
>   hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm.pollChanges(TeamFoundationServerScm.java:187)
>     at hudson.scm.SCM.poll(SCM.java:373)    at
>   hudson.model.AbstractProject.poll(AbstractProject.java:1667)  at
>   hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.runPolling(SCMTrigger.java:454)     at
>   hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.run(SCMTrigger.java:487)    at
>   hudson.util.SequentialExecutionQueue$QueueEntry.run(SequentialExecutionQueue.java:133)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I go to the link http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Spawning+processes+from+build and it doesn't help me.  If I'm spawning processes then I'm not doing it on purpose and that's what it seems to be designed to help me do...Spawn Processes.

I also googled "Hudson Service won't start" and the results show a symptom that isn't true for me...War file is zero length.  Mine isn't.  And even if it was it tells me to copy the original War file to my hundson directory.   I don't know where I would find a Hudson.war file that I would consider Original.

I did recently install the ThinBackup plugin if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't occur to me to mention that the box Hudson is on is restricted from the Internet.  I had IT re-enable the internet and the service started without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone else coming in here via a search or something, I ran into a very similar situation with my Hudson (Jenkins) server.

I was only able to get a successful restart after opening up connectivity to `http://178.255.83.1:80`. This seems to be a [OCSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol) server, so the traffic seems legitimate.